# Show Data from Database in a multiple Dropdown using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm using Chosen.js to show multi select dropdown menus in my forms.
All these selected data by a user goes to a mysql database in a single string separated by a ";". So far, so good.

Now my problem is, I want to give my users a edit form, where they can edit all there given data. So I have to read out the data from the database and shown this up on the form. But what is the right way for a multi select dropdown menu?

```
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
```

Data saved in Database like:
"21;22;23".

I'm really stuck at this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your data in array like

`$selected_items= explode( ";", "21;22;23" );`

then use `in_array( $option_value, $selected_items );` to detect if that option is selected.

Comment: Yea, thats it...this is so embarrassing. Bring the data back to an array and search for the values...thank you for this thought-provoking impulse.

Answer (score 0):

Look into how you can- [Normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data

Till you do that, you can have a hack of splitting the string with `;`

`var data =  "21;22;23"; var ids = data.split(';')` will give you an array

of the ids `["21", "22", "23"]`

Iterate over the ids and create your dropdown elements.

```
var html = '';
$.each(ids, function(id) {
   html += '<option value="' + id + "'>' + id + '</option>';
});

$('.some-dropdown').html(html);
```